# actionSupport InputText Onchange Not Firing

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm racking my brain over this. Its a simple on change function which should fire but when I test in my org, I never get the debug "here" despite getting the rest in my class. I've looked over dozens of different google results and the code is identical. Does anyone know if SF is just broken?

```
public class testController {

    public static String testNewString {get;set;}

    public testController(){}

    public static Boolean isAccountAvailable()
    {
        System.debug('here');

        List<Account> tempList = ([SELECT Id 
                                            FROM Account 
                                            WHERE Name = :testNewString]);

        if(tempList.size() != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

<apex:page controller="testController" docType="html-5.0">
     <apex:form id="form1">
        <apex:inputText value="{!testNewString }" html-placeholder="New Sales Order #">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" action="{!isAccountAvailable}" rerender="form1"  />
              </apex:inputText>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

For whoever is looking for an answer, the fix for this code snippet is subtle. Make sure the function returns a page reference. Making fields global might help make it visible to VF.

```
public class TestController {

public String testNewString {get;set;}

public testController(){}

public PageReference isAccountAvailable()
{
    System.debug('here');

    List<Account> tempList = ([SELECT Id 
                                        FROM Account 
                                        WHERE Name = :testNewString]);

    if(tempList.size() != 0)
    {
        System.debug('true');
    }
    else
    {
        System.debug('false');
    }

    return null;
}

}


<apex:page controller="TestController" docType="html-5.0">
     <apex:form id="form1">
        <apex:inputText value="{!testNewString}"  html-placeholder="New Sales Order #">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!isAccountAvailable}" rerender="form1"  />
              </apex:inputText>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```